# Create PDF document from WordPress article links

Tags: pdf, website

I have website created in WordPress. I posted more than 30 articles on my site. Now I want to create a PDF from links to my articles. For example, my article is http://www.dogmal.com/boerboel/ and I want to create a PDF document from it with all images properly formatted.

Answer (score 1):

[Sejda PDF](https://www.sejda.com)'s [HTML to PDF](https://www.sejda.com/html-to-pdf) tool can help you convert web pages to PDF documents.

The resulting PDFs look just like the web pages do in the browser.

https://www.sejda.com/html-to-pdf

Disclaimer: I work at Sejda.